# Creating a csv file by loading multiple images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, export-to-csv

I am working on a machine learning problem of classifying different types of leaves using the flavia dataset. I have a dataset folder that has 32 sub folders each containing some images of the respective class. The images are grayscale of dimension 4096x1.
How can i load all these images from all the subfolders at once and then create a csv file from the stored pixel values ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a cell array with all the filenames, e.g.

```
C{1} = '/path/to/file1.png';
C{2} = '/path/to/file2.png';
```

etc. (there are several ways to do this automatically, but given I have no information on your file structure and there aren't that many files, let's skip this step. )

Then have a for loop

```
for n = 1 : 32
  I = imread(C{n});
  csvwrite('my_csv_file.csv', I(:).', '-append');
end
```

PS. The `(:).'` syntax ensures each image becomes a row.

Comment: Actually i have 32 subfolders each with the name of a particular leaf type. For eg. the folder named chinese tulip will have around 60-70 images of chinese tulip. So like this there are 32 folders each containing 60-70 images. So the dataset in total has around 2000 images.. it wont be possible to creat a cell array for each image separately. How can i solve this issue?